# Using vapply to assign function to coordinates

Tags: r

I'm being threatened with having to hand draw hundreds of circles in PowerPoint with a very short turnaround and so I'm looking to R to do this for me. Forgive me, I've never programmed before, and I'm leaping straight in.

Essentially I'm drawing a scatterplot on a timeline. This I've done easily using ggplot2. Unfortuantely due to the hundreds of dots involved I need to be able to space them out so all can be seen. Jitter is not an option as I don't know my final number of dots. Therefore, I'm trying to build something which will eventually know how many dots are in a quadrant. First of all, I'm trying to assign my co-ordinates a value within a range:

```
    getxcordinate <- function (x) {
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  runif(1,x-1,x)
}

getycordinate <- function (y) {
    y<- as.numeric(y)
    runif(1,y-1,y)
}

getxcordinate(x = my.data$t_score[1])
getycordinate(y = my.data$Geography[1])


#Precreate the offset as numeric x-y coordinates that so that the points and the text can refer to the same coordinates later  
my.data$moved_t_score <- vapply(my.data$t_score,getxcordinate, any)
my.data$moved_Geography <- vapply(my.data$moved_Geography,getycordinate, any)
```

From the help I can see that vapply needs something called FUN.VALUE in order to work. I tried "any" but that was optimistic - what is it I should be doing?

Thanks!

Comment: `FUN.VALUE` is the length and class of the value you know will be returned from running `FUN`.  In order to use `vapply()`, you must know the length and class of the return values, if `x` is a list, the lengths of all the returned list elements must be the same.  For example, to return a length 3 character vector, then `FUN.VALUE = character(3)`  You may want `sapply()` as `vapply()` is confusing for new R users.

Comment: Its not clear from the description or the subset of code exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Some sample data with sample desired output usually helps. If you are just trying to jitter, then odds are you _can_ use jitter -- see its optional arguments.